# Javascript - Input change events inside iframes

Tags: javascript, iframe

Is it possible to detect input change events inside an iframe?

The code needs to be pure Javascript and sit outside the iframe. Everytime I type in an input field INSIDE the iframe, the function needs to fire - is this possible??

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var iframe = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];
    iframe.onload = function() {
        var input = iframe.contentDocument.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
        input.addEventListener('keypress', function() {
            // wait until key is entered into input box
            setTimeout(function() {
                console.log(input.value);
            }, 10);
        }, false);
    };
};
```

Comment: Is there any way to use the 'change' event or onchange or something similar - so that I can catch the input being changed without keypress - stuff would get added inside the input dynamically.

Comment: @user1775598 there is 'change' event but it's not trigered on keypress but on blur if content changed, (in Google Chrome, don't know other browsers). And change event is not triggered either if you set the value using javascript.

Comment: Is there any way to catch the input change if the value of the input is being set dynamically through Javascript?

Comment: @user1775598 I don't think so, unless you create a function that set the value and that function execute an event.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on the same domain you have access to the iframe.

```
document.getElementById('yourIframe').contentWindow.document.findElementsByTagName('input')[0].onkeyup = function () {
    console.log('Input has changed.');
};
```

If you are on a different domain you best bet is the postMessage API desribed here: http://davidwalsh.name/window-postmessage
The consequence for this solution is, you'll have to write JS on both sides, the iframe and the parent frame.

Comment: he said pure Javascript

Comment: Sorry. I fix that. But the same origin policy problem remains.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('rw_iframe').contentWindow.document.getElementById("fieldID").onchange = function () {
                
};
```

Using jquery changes the current context, as long as you use js to attach an event to iframe elements, it will work